# I want to stay on the same page after adding product into the cart. Don't want to go to cart/checkout or on product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Currently I am using astra free theme and elementor page builder. It redirects me to the product page after adding the product into the cart I want to stay on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce already gives you the possibility to deactivate this behaviour in the settings.

In your wordpress backend, go to Woocommerce -> Settings -> Choose the tab "Products"

You will find a section called "Add to cart behaviour".
Deactivate the checkbox with the label "Redirect to the cart page after successful addition".

Comment: That is already checked. Maybe I was not more clear in my question. I am not on product page I am on archive page from where when I click on the add to cart button it add the product into the cart but also redirect me to the product page. I don't want to go to either cart or to the product page I want to stay on that archive page.